# Is it OK to ask for a reccomendation of a Wordpress specif host within the uk?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question to get a recommendation for UK based web-hosts that specalise in WordPress.

Is this acceptable or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this makes great question, but I don't think it's clearly out of scope either.

As for me:

- asking for generic hosting recommendation (with minimal WP specifics, because many hosts market bogus WP expertise) **is not** fine;
- asking for hosting that only offers WP or truly specializes in it - **is**.

Also try to make your question more useful for anyone. Even if you are interested in UK only it is probably better to ask about specialized hosting in general and mention UK preference (not as hard requirement).

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, I will see what others have to say before posting, last thing I want is 50 down votes!

Comment: Would also be less than optimal getting spammed with "answers" that contain referral links or self-plugs.

Comment: I think the question could very well fit the scope. I would recommend making it more universally beneficial, as @Rarst mentioned, perhaps by asking for **ideal** (as opposed to the trivial, minimal) specs for a WordPress-specific web host. (And not just PHP/SQL specs, but configurations, resource limits/quotas, customer support, etc.) I think any "list of hosts" is probably non-ideal for WPSE, since "lists of things" are generally discouraged in the SE Q-and-A model.

Comment: @Chip there already is [question about ideal hosting specsl](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266/best-of-breed-features-of-a-high-end-wordpress-web-host)

Comment: @Rarst too true. I didn't say that it wouldn't be a *duplicate* question; just that it would be *appropriate*. :)